# setting min threadcount with UseLibuv Ubuntu System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException'

Tags: .net-core, cross-platform, ubuntu-18.04, asp.net-core-2.1, kestrel-http-server

I have asp.net core 2.1.6 application
It is running fine on Windows with IIS

```
 public static IWebHostBuilder BuildWebHost(string[] args) => WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<StartupShutdownHandler>()
               .UseLibuv(o => o.ThreadCount = 1000)  //todo to explore concurrent connection option
                ;
```

when I tried to run same application on ubuntu i am not able to start and getting some exception. When I comment out UseLibuv(o => o.ThreadCount = 1000) line then it runs.

Exception i am getting is

```
Info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
      User profile is available. Using '/home/devops/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' as key repository; keys will not be encrypted at rest.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[58]
      Creating key {0184c7ca-fe6a-40dc-979f-152a89b50560} with creation date 2019-10-08 14:36:01Z, activation date 2019-10-08 14:36:01Z, and expiration date 2020-01-06 14:36:01Z.
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
      No XML encryptor configured. Key {0184c7ca-fe6a-40dc-979f-152a89b50560} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository[39]
      Writing data to file '/home/devops/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys/key-0184c7ca-fe6a-40dc-979f-152a89b50560.xml'.
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Unable to bind to http://localhost:5000 on the IPv4 loopback interface: 'Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.'.
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Unable to bind to http://localhost:5000 on the IPv6 loopback interface: 'Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.'.
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Unable to start Kestrel.
System.IO.IOException: Failed to bind to address http://localhost:5000. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.) (Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.) ---> System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
   at System.Threading.Thread.StartInternal()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Libuv.Internal.LibuvThread.StartAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Libuv.Internal.LibuvTransport.BindAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.<>c__DisplayClass22_0`1.<<StartAsync>g__OnBind|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindEndpointAsync(ListenOptions endpoint, AddressBindContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.LocalhostListenOptions.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.LocalhostListenOptions.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.DefaultAddressStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(IServerAddressesFeature addresses, KestrelServerOptions serverOptions, ILogger logger, Func`2 createBinding)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Unhandled Exception: System.IO.IOException: Failed to bind to address http://localhost:5000. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.) (Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.) ---> System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
   at System.Threading.Thread.StartInternal()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Libuv.Internal.LibuvThread.StartAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Libuv.Internal.LibuvTransport.BindAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.<>c__DisplayClass22_0`1.<<StartAsync>g__OnBind|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindEndpointAsync(ListenOptions endpoint, AddressBindContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.LocalhostListenOptions.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.LocalhostListenOptions.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.DefaultAddressStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(IServerAddressesFeature addresses, KestrelServerOptions serverOptions, ILogger logger, Func`2 createBinding)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.RunAsync(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token, String shutdownMessage)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.RunAsync(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.Run(IWebHost host)
   at Auth.Interfaces.Program.Main(String[] args)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per suggestion on github i have removed UseLibuv option